# Nodejs Immediately delete generated file

Tags: node.js, pdf, dropbox, fs, unlink

I'm trying to delete a pdf immediately after is has been generated in `node.js`. The generated pdf is sent as an email attachment, uploaded to `dropbox` and then deleted from the local file system. But as i try to delete it , it does not delete it and it does not send the email either. The pdf is created using `html-pdf`. Here is my code :

```
     if (result) {
       var filename = user.number+ ".pdf";
       var path = './public/files/'+filename ;
       var options = { filename: path, format: 'Legal', orientation: 'portrait', directory: './public/files/',type: "pdf" };
       html = result;
       pdf.create(html, options).toFile(function(err, res) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(res);
      });
     var dbx = new dropbox({ accessToken: mytoken });
     fs.readFile( path,function (err, contents) {
            if (err) {
                   console.log('Error: ', err);
            }
            dbx.filesUpload({ path: "/"+filename ,contents: contents })
                           .then(function (response) {
                            console.log("done")
                            console.log(response);
                           })
                            .catch(function (err) {
                             console.log(err);
                             });
                            });

            var mailOptions = {
            from: 'xyz', // sender address
            to: user.email, // list of receivers
            subject: 'Confirmation received', // Subject line
            attachments : [{
                            filename: filename,
                            path : path                                                                           
                           }]
                     };

            transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
                if (error) {
                               return console.log(error);
                           }
                                 console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);

                               });
             fs.unlinkSync(path); // even tried fs.unlink , does not delete file
            // fs.unlinkSync(someother file); this one works
 }
```

So when i do `fs.unlink' or`fs.unlinkSync`, if the file is already there it works but the files that is generated as in path doesn't get deleted.

Comment: You need to wait until you finish sending the email.

Comment: console.log is your best friend here, if you print something instead of `unlinkSync(path)` you will notice that your `Message sent [...]` occurs after your attempt to delete the file

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs is asynchronous so you need to handle every blocks properly. your code shows that some times before completely creating the PDF itself the file upload to dropbox will start if the PDF creation is slow.

And deletion of the PDF file happens before the mail sending, so you get some err but you did not logged you error in `fs.unlink()`. Divide you code as blocks and use callback for better performance and flow.

Your code should be like this to work properly..

```
if (result) {
 var filename = user.number+ ".pdf";
 var path = './public/files/'+filename ;
 var options = { filename: path, format: 'Legal', orientation: 'portrait', directory: './public/files/',type: "pdf" };
 html = result;
 //Generate the PDF first
 pdf.create(html, options).toFile(function(err, res) {
   if (err){
     return console.log(err);
   } else {
      //If success then read the PDF file and then upload to dropbox
     var dbx = new dropbox({ accessToken: mytoken });
     fs.readFile( path,function (err, contents) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error: ', err);
        } else {
          dbx.filesUpload({path: "/"+filename ,contents: contents }).then(function (response) {
            // Once the file upload is done then send mail
            console.log("done")
            sendMail('xyz', user.email, 'Confirmation received', filename, path, function(err, result){
              // once mail is successful then delete the file finally
              fs.unlinkSync(path); //if you need you can use callback with this for confirmation of deletion
            });
           }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
           });
        }
    });
   }
});

function sendMail(sender, receiver, subject, filename, path, callback){
  var mailOptions = {
    from: sender, // sender address
    to: receiver, // list of receivers
    subject: subject, // Subject line
    attachments : [{
      filename: filename,
      path : path
    }]
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (error) {
       callback(err, null);
     } else {
       console.log('Message %s sent: %s', info.messageId, info.response);
       callback(null, info)
     }
  });
}
}
```